# print only one key from request get json

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/xoec/?__a=1')

print(r.json())
```

Does anyone know how I can only print the `profile_pic_url_hd` key from the JSON??

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/xoec/?__a=1')

print(r.json()['profile_pic_url_hd'])
```

Comment: Why do you think that this request should return json?

Comment: You can paste a JSON [here](https://jsonlint.com/) to have a better view of it. Then you can learn more on how to retrieve data from it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON).

Answer (score 0):

It's a nested dict

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/xoec/?__a=1')
data = r.json()
print(data['graphql']['user']['profile_pic_url_hd'])
```

output

```
https://instagram.fsof9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/258870257_928417817813687_4461353210299960538_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fsof9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=111&_nc_ohc=KNK65uHe5jIAX88lBNK&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT9qkUTrIturlocM8n7oQ9cNnNcrImSAFOePyIWEAfsNuQ&oe=61FDDC5F&_nc_sid=7bff83
```